# Cron job doesn't initiate backtick assignment

Tags: shell-script, cron

```
#!/bin/bash

# taking the count of file whose name matches with FOO
file_check=$(ls -1 $HOME/*FOO* 2>/dev/null | wc -l) 

echo "$file_check" >> $HOME/Test1.log
```

Given there are 2 files which are having FOO in their file name,

When run script manually output in Test1.log is 2,

While running via Crontab output in Test1.log is 0,

what am i doing wrong here?

Crontab entry

```
#2 12 1,2,3,4,6 * *  $HOME/test1.sh 2>&1
```

I tried following variants,

```
file_check=`(ls -1 $HOME/*FOO* 2>/dev/null | wc -l)`
```

Comment: thank you for pointing out @roaima, I have added the entry

Comment: running on Linux server box -  version 2.6.32-754.18.2.el6.x86_64

Comment: Are there any directories with `FOO` in their name?

Comment: only files with FOO in their file name

Comment: i added the entry in crontab file via crontab -e option

Comment: Is it possible that at 12:02 on those six days of the month there are no `FOO` files, and actually your code is working as expected (there's nothing significantly wrong with it).

Comment: Have you tried redirecting stderr to a file, instead of discarding it? This may help you troubleshoot it.

Comment: I was running the cron with foo files present in the directory also validated the same results when running manually.

I also tried piping stderr to a file but no errors seen in the file

Comment: That leading `#` character is not really present in the crontab entry, right?

Comment: not present that is just used for formatting code in unix.stackexchange platform